# Submitting edited entries in Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible using Freeform for users to log in and edit their form submission in multiple visits, and only send an email notification once they have finished with the form and change its status to eg ‘completed’, (meaning they can then no longer edit it)?

(Using EE5 and assume that Freeform Next would be the way to go, unless Classic is the only way to handle it.)

Comment: You might get a better answer if you give some details about which version EE and which version of Freeform you are using.  Both have multiple versions with differing capabilities.

Comment: Good point. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible with editing of Freeform submissions. There's no way to suppress or differentiate between email notifications when initially submitting / editing / finish editing.

The closest you might get to stimulating this would be to use the [Dynamic Template Notifications](https://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/v1/overview/email-notifications.html#dynamic-template-notifications) feature and have 2 or 3 different templates that load the form. The first one could have no notifications setup at all, and be meant to be the initial submit of the form. The second (or however many other ones necessary) can also have no notifications setup, and then the final template could have the notifications setup with the Dynamic Template Notifications option to finally send out the notification. :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be crazy, but a long time ago in EE2 + FreeForm Pro, I could have sworn on multi-page forms a user could do, say, the first page, leave the website, then come back, and it would be populated. The user would need to submit and go to another page for it to save, though.